# Why is MkSimpleSolver not equivalent to MkSolver("smt") with Z3?

Tags: z3

I'm experimenting with Z3 tactics. I noticed that the solver returned by

```
context.MkSimpleSolver()
```

has a different performance profile than the solver

```
context.MkSolver(context.MkTactic("smt"))
```

I understand that the "smt" tactic is supposed to perform the most general algorithm that Z3 has. So both these solvers should have identical output. Given this, why do they have different performance profiles?

I am testing this on a formula that is quantified over a bitvector. The quantifier body makes use of integers and bitvectors. The simple solver returns immediately with sat. The other one takes longer than I was willing to wait.

(If it helps here is a little background: I am trying to make Z3 bit-blast all integer terms to bitvectors hoping that this speeds things up. All integers involved are constrained to [0, 3]. I'm trying to get the `bit-blast` tactic to "take".)

Comment: I can see why the question makes sense: semantically you may expect the same result. However, the code paths and especially the way formulas are pre-processed for these two approaches are different, so I can imagine they produce different performance profiles.

Comment: @NikolajBjorner is there a way I can find out, what MkSimpleSolver produces so that I can replicate it (and make minor adjustments)? Is it possible to replicate MkSimpleSolver with MkSolver at all?